# Trigger Variable Does not Exist - No methods

Tags: apex, trigger, error-messages

Other questions on this topic are referencing high-level coding solutions that I'm not capable of at the moment. I am attempting to write a low level trigger that updates fields. This is extremely simple, but all the solutions I'm finding are above and beyond what I want to know. Ask_Ready_Date__c is a field on the Opportunity object. I'm working off trailheads, so I feel the syntax is fairly straightforward - what unknown rule am I violating here?

My main theory is that custom fields are not available to reference on standard object for some reason.

My error: Variable Ask_Ready_Date__c does not exist.

```
trigger FinancialPlanning on Opportunity (before update) {
    for (Opportunity x : Trigger.new) {
        // update this field with a date that is a year in the future
         x.Ask_Ready_Date__c = Ask_Ready_Date__c + 365;

    }

}
```

Comment: Pretty sure the += expression operator would work in this case. `x.Ask_Ready_Date__c += 365;`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're not referencing a standard object; it's trying to find a variable called Ask_Ready_Date__c, which does not exist. The fix is to simply add an object reference:

```
trigger FinancialPlanning on Opportunity (before update) {
    for (Opportunity x : Trigger.new) {
        // update this field with a date that is a year in the future
         x.Ask_Ready_Date__c = x.Ask_Ready_Date__c + 365;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand. I'm thinking this is x.Ask_Ready_Date__c is a variable that holds itself + 365.

Comment: @raisl Breaking this down, it's assigned from right to left: `x.Ask_Ready_Date__c + 365` gets a date one year in the future, then `x.Ask_Ready_Date__c = ...` assigns the result back in to the variable.